# Bean Property Access and Annotations

Tags: java, reflection, apache-commons-beanutils

Are there any java libraries which allow me to utilize BeanUtils like property access `bean.prop1.prop2` while allowing access to the annotations on the getter/field itself?

For example, I have a bean class that looks like this:

```
public class Child {
  @SomeCustomAnnotation
  private String name;
  //standard bean getter setters
  }

public class Parent {
  private Child child;
  //standard bean getter setters
}
```

And I would like to be able to retrieve not only the value of the property I'm looking for but also any annotations annotated on that field that's value is being returned:

```
String childsName = SomeLibrary.getValue(parent, "child.name");
Annotation[] annotationsOnChildsName = SomeLibrary.getAnnotations(parent, "child.name");
```

Do any libraries exist which allow both features?  I can use Commons BeanUtils to do pure property access for values and Plain Reflection to get the annotations on properties, but there doesn't seem to be a way to combine both abilities.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something you can just the reflection's [Field](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class

```
Field f = Parent.class.getField("name");
Object value = f.get(parent);
f.getAnnotations();
```

Comment: The nuance here is I would like to be able to support access through standard java bean conventions (ie. `getName()` and the field `name`) as well as nested properties

Comment: I was thinking about this and not sure this is really possible, ie: you could only do it based on convention.  For example, my private field may not be named the same as the getter setter or even be the same type.

Comment: `getField` only gives publicly accessible field, use `getDeclaredField` to obtain protected fields